# Applying if statement to range of cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, range

I have a small range of cells, C6:C10. I'm trying to apply an if statement to this range of cells using VBA code. Currently, my code takes the output of the if statement for the first cell (C6), and replicates that value for cells C7:C10. The if statement is correct, I'm just not sure how to apply it to a range of cells in a column.

```
Sub Cleanup()
Dim Segment As String
Dim i As Integer
Segment = ActiveCell(6, 3).Value
For i = 6 To 10
    If Right(Left(Segment, 6), 1) = "/" Then
        ActiveCell(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 5)
    Else
        ActiveCell(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 6)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `ActiveCell` to `Cells`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine if you use Cells instead of ActiveCell, except that you'll have to change your loop to go from 7 to 10 or else it will over-write the original cell as well as C7:C10.

```
Sub Cleanup()
Dim Segment As String
Dim i As Integer
Segment = Cells(6, 3).Value
For i = 7 To 10
    If Right(Left(Segment, 6), 1) = "/" Then
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 5)
    Else
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 6)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Cleanup()
    Dim Segment As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Segment = Cells(i, 3).Value
    For i = 7 To 10
        If Right(Left(Segment, 6), 1) = "/" Then
            cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 5)
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 6)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So after changing my code to this one, it's now giving me an error code of 400.  I guess my code is referring to something that does not exist or no longer exists anymore, i'm not sure why changing the 6 to an "i" in line 4 caused this. Just to clarify, i'm not looking to replicate what's in cell C6 downwards, I just want the if statement to apply to the cells following C6

Answer (score 0):

here three (out of many other) possible codes, in simplicity order (the last being more simple than the first):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Cleanup()
    Dim Segment As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 6 To 10
        Segment = Cells(i, 3).Value '<== Cells(i, 3) is the current cell as per the current row (i)
        If Mid(Segment, 6, 1) = "/" Then
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 5)
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Segment, 6)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Sub Cleanup2()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 6 To 10
        With Cells(i, 3) 'avoid repetitions (and a variable, too) by using 'With' keyword and implying 'Cells(i, 3)' preceeds every dot (".") till next 'End With" statement
            If Right(Left(.Value, 6), 1) = "/" Then
                .Value = Left(.Value, 5)
            Else
                .Value = Left(.Value, 6)
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub


Sub Cleanup3()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 6 To 10
        With Cells(i, 3)
            .Value = Left(.Value, IIf(Mid(.Value, 6, 1) = "/", 5, 6)) ' use Iif function to avoid multiple lines. Also use 'Mid' function in lieu of 'Right(Left(..))'
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```