# If "iserror" FOR loop with varying object type

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, for-loop, variable-types

I have a column that has either string types (ex. "N/A") or numbers in it. I'm trying to write a vba code that if the FOR loop comes across a string type it'll be converted to a 0. Essentially what's happening is the code goes down a column (K) of values (ex. $10, $600, $5200, N/A, $5), and keeps the cell value if it's a number and if a cell has text in it then the text is converted to a 0. The range is (K6:K10), the formula would look something like,

```
=If(iserror(K6/10) = TRUE, 0, K6)
```

Code:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim DilutedRev As Integer
For a = 6 To 10
    DilutedRev = ActiveCell(a, 11).Value
    If IsError(DilutedRev / 100) = True Then
        ActiveCell(a, 11) = 0
    Else
        ActiveCell(i, 11) = DilutedRev
    End If
```

Comment: There's no question...

Comment: Sigh. Why do people never learn from their [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37142200/applying-if-statement-to-range-of-cells-using-vba) XD

Comment: Nothing happens when I run this code so I'm curious to know what's wrong. I'm not sure if you can establish DilutedRev as an integer type when there are varying object types in the column

Comment: @Davey `Nothing happens when I run this code so I'm curious to know what's wrong.` _Please_ go back to your last question and answer that yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [IsNumeric function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx) to determine if the cell contains a number.

```
Dim a As Long

With ActiveSheet
    For a = 6 To 10
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(a, "K").Value2) Then
            .Cells(a, 11) = CLng(.Cells(a, "K").Value2)
        Else
            .Cells(a, 11) = 0
        End If
    Next a
End With
```

Using the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) like you did was not 'best practise' due to the relative origin point¹; better to use the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

VBA functions that return boolean values (e.g. [IsNumeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1.aspx), [IsError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278547.aspx), etc) do not have to be compared to True or False. They are already either True or False.

I've used the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) to check but the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) could be used just as well.

It is usually worthwhile explicitly defining the [Range.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) worksheet  property rather then relying implicitly on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx).

---

¹ <sub>Strictly speaking, there is nothing wrong with offsetting the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) as you did but the result is completely relative to the current selection on the worksheet and is generally not considered 'best practise'. With D5 selected on the worksheet, `activecell(1,1)` references D5 and `activecell(2,3)` references F6. In a very special circumstance, this behavior may be desirable but generally speaking it is better to use the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) and use the *row_number* and *column_number* to reference the cell from the [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) perspective, not as an offset position from the ActiveCell.</sub>

Comment: Wow, how many footnote opportunities missed?!?! tsk tsk Jeeped.

Comment: /hides in shame XD

Answer (score 4):

First as it was pointed out in your last question; Activecell refers to just that the activecell it is one cell and not a range.  You want Cells().

Next by redeclaring the variable inside the loop it allows Excel to determine its type each time.  If not it will be the type that excel assigns the first time and you cannot store a text value in an Integer type.

Then we test that variable if it is numeric or not.

But you could skip that and do what @Jeeped suggests.

```
Dim a As Integer

For a = 6 To 10
    Dim DilutedRev 
    DilutedRev = Cells(a, 11).Value
    If Not isnumeric(DilutedRev) Then
        Cells(a, 11) = 0
    Else
        Cells(a, 11) = DilutedRev
    End If
```

Comment: `Cell()`? or `Cells()`? I think your computer has been hijacked/compromised!

Comment: @BruceWayne yeah yeah... Sometimes I jump on one thing and miss others.  It is why I surround myself with people like you guys.  I go fast and expect others to tell me when I messed it up.  Thanks.

Comment: So much for being God. Guess superhero is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate the help. Obviously I don't know too much on VBA. I just started learning.

Comment: @Davey you should consider accepting one of the answers.

Comment: @Davey you should mark Jeeped's answer as correct.  It has better information.

Comment: @Jeeped as have I so it makes very little difference to me.  I feel yours is a better answer, as it usually is.